# Why is iPhone 6 Plus' screen size 375x667 on real device?

Tags: ios

I write a simple universal app (Objective-C), and found when running on real device iPhone 6 Plus, in LLVM I view `[UIScreen mainScreen].size` is:

```
(lldb) po [UIScreen mainScreen]
<UIScreen: 0x144502cd0; bounds = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x170028f60; size = 1125.000000 x 2001.000000>>
```

but while using simulator, iPhone 6 Plus:

```
(lldb) po [UIScreen mainScreen]
<UIScreen: 0x7fd933008300; bounds = {{0, 0}, {414, 736}}; mode = <UIScreenMode: 0x7fd9333004e0; size = 1242.000000 x 2208.000000>>
```

Comment: Is the real device set to a zoomed resolution mode? You can check this in **Settings > Display & Brightness > View**. If not, are you sure the real device is actually a 6 Plus and not a 6?

Comment: Do you have al the correct launch screens or launch NIB?

Comment: @PartuallyFinite, you are great.

Comment: Set the launch screen file as MainStoryBoard and the app will launch without scaling. Then, see if that changes the dimensions. If it does, you will need to set the proper sized images for launch image. Without the correct sized launch images for 6 and 6plus, it launches the app in a scaled mode.

Comment: @DienBell was the device in zoomed resolution mode?

Comment: @PartiallyFinite yes, device is in zoomed mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that the device isn't set to the zoomed resolution mode in **Settings > Display & Brightness > View.**

Setting the phone to a zoomed resolution will result in a different point size to be returned for the screen, which seems to be what you are experiencing.